# Using JSONAPI with service

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

can I use the jsonapi like that in a service?

```
//services/pics.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    findAll: function(){
        return Ember.$.getJSON('http://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=0&pageSize=15');
    }

    });
```

I'm trying but I can't see anything in the page. And no errors on chrome DevTools.

//components/image-list.hbs

```
{{#each model as |pic|}}
  <div>{{#link-to "pic" pic}}    
     <p class="info">{{pic.Title}}</p><br/>
     <img src={{pic.Image}} width="300">
  {{/link-to}}</div>
{{/each}}
{{yield}}
```

//templates/index.hbs

```
{{image-list model=model currentPos=currentPos }}
{{outlet}}
```

//routes/pic.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    activate: function() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    },

    pics: Ember.inject.service(),
    model(params) {
        console.info(params, "Params");
        return this.get('pics').get('pics').find(function(item){
            if(Ember.isEqual(params.NewsUrl,item.NewsUrl)){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });
} 
});
```

//routes/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    pics: Ember.inject.service(),
    model() {
        console.log(this.get('pics').get('pics'));
        return this.get('pics').get('pics');
    }

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not use `ember-data`, which `store` *is* a service. If you don't use `ember-data` you would have to manually parse and process the JSONAPI Response.

Comment: I tried that. I couldn't do it. Then now I'm trying service stuff. But if you can help this is when I was trying it with a store : https://ember-twiddle.com/fe9009abc8ecec2b4b48c91c64c8ff77?openFiles=twiddle.json%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs  you can't see the data here becuse my api is not https:/ though but you can check the code

Comment: first you should not call `Ember.$.getJSON` but override `urlForFindAll`. Checkout the [API](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_urlForFindAll) and the code. Next if you use ember data, why would you call `Ember.$.getJSON` *again* in the routes model hook? Ask your store for it: `this.store.findAll('news-list')`. Next your API is *not* `JSONAPI` compatible. So don't use the `JSONAPIAdapter`&`JSONAPISerializer`.

Comment: now using DS.ApplicationAdapter instead of DS.JSONAPIAdapter. And in my adapter I call `return urlForFindAll('http://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=0&pageSize=15');` and in the route I call the store as         return `this.store.findAll('news-list');` But on the index route I get errors one of them is 404 not found and other 2 is cannot get /news-lists. Also I dont have a serializer, should I create one? What exactly am I gone do with it

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could, but I think you should return your getJSON call result from your route's model hook.

If your goal here is to reuse the data in different routes then you should define a pic model and configure the matching JSONAPIAdapter to point to your API. Then you'll be able to call this.store.findAll('pic') in your model hook to fetch all the images from the API.

Check the guides about model definition: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/models/

and also about how to customize adapters: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: I tried that also. I deleted service, created a model news-list.js and put attributes in it, then created and adapter and put the getJSON code in it. Then I tried to use his.store.findAll('pic') but I can't get the data. this is the twiddle but you cant see the data here because my api's https// doesnt respond https:// https://ember-twiddle.com/fe9009abc8ecec2b4b48c91c64c8ff77?openFiles=twiddle.json%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs